# 3 questions on upgrading CakePHP from version 1.3.6 to 2.3.5

Tags: cakephp-2.3

- Beginner at PHP so please excuse for my ignorance.
- Need to change a CakePHP project from version 1.3.16 to 2.3.5.
- So far did these things-

  1. Reviewed websites about upgrading 1.3 to 2.0 and 2.x and read a blog tutorial on CakePHP.
  2. Got the 1.3.16 version of project to work in inetpub\wwwroot\proj.
  3. Installed CakePHP 2.3.5 and put it in inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp235.
  4. Found page [http://localhost/cake235] that says "CakePHP:the rapid developement framework", the version of PHP, if the tmp dir is writable, etc.
  5. Changed new app\config\core.php security.salt, security.cipherseed to old values.
  6. Changed new app\config\default.php datasource, login, password, database to old values.
  7. Changed app\config\bootstrap.php, added require_once(APP.'config'.DS.'constants.php'); from old.
  8. Copied app\config\constants.php from old to new area.
- Now want to

  1. Copy in the models, views, and controllers from the old to new area.
  2. Use the upgrade shell to start the change from 1.3.16. to 2.3.5.
- Questions

  1. Is there anything else needed with configuration ?
  2. Is the upgrade shell run by typing "upgradeshell all" at inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp235\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Upgradeshell.php ?
  3. If so, will running the upgrade shell change anything in the old but running 1.3.16 version directories or just in the new 2.3.5 directories ?

Comment: Although the upgrade shell should *help* migrating to CakePHP 2, some manual changes probably will have to be made. It should not make changes to the other (old) website, because that is a whole separate installation, however backing up your old website (and database!) is always a good thing. Having a version-control system also helps to allow rolling back unwanted changes.

Comment: can you be more specific.. do you get any error? - I advise you first install version 2 when you see every thing is working then import all the MVC-vendors and shells in correct places after that you need to update Views of your 1.3 code to 2.x e.g. $form->input('name') change to=> $this->Html->input('name') and other elements